# Order of element in multiplicative group modulo n, where n is not prime

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, multiplicative-order

I should calculate order of a givent element of multiplicative group modulo *n*. This *n* might, or might not be a prime.

I discovered that I can use algorithm 4.79 from Handbook of Applied Cryptography to do that:
[image]

The thing is, I need to know order of the group itself as input for this algorithm. For a group where *n* is prime, this is easy, the order is *n-1*. But what if *n* is a composite number? Do I really have to calculate the Euler totient function ([as suggested here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_modulo_n)) to determine the order of the group and then use this algorithm to calculate the order of the element? Or am I somehow able to calculate the order of a given element based on just factorization of *n* (teacher suggested this should be possible)?

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\varphi(n)$ from a factorization of $n$?  The link you gave links to a page giving a general formula in terms of the factorization of $n$.

Comment: No, I don't, that's the thing.

Comment: the group (Z/mZ)* has order n = phi(m). Be careful not to confuse n and m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You link to the "[Multiplicative group modulo n](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_modulo_n)" page on Groupprops.  That page references the "Euler-phi function" with a link to the "[Euler totient function](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Euler-phi_function)" page on Groupprops.  That page has an "Explicit formula" section with $$ \varphi(n) = n \prod_{p \mid n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}  \right) $$ (although the cited page indicates "$p \mid n$" with the words "over all distinct prime factors of $n$").

Thus, the reference you give tells you how to compute $\varphi(n)$ from a prime factorization of $n$.  The method given is relatively fast.

Comment: Actually, the formula is different, but it is in the "Explicit formula" section of the page and it works! Thanks!

Comment: And over just *p*, not *p|n* :)

Comment: @arctictern : Fixed further.  It is clearly time for me to back away from the keyboard...

Comment: @HonzaKalfus : '[T]he cited page indicates "$p \mid n$" with the words "over all distinct prime factors of $n$"'.

Comment: Ah, right, I get it :)

Answer (score -1):

**Hint** Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

By the CRT, if $$n=p_1^{e_1}...p_k^{e_k}$$
then the order of $a$ modulo $n$ is the least common multiple of the order of $a$ modulo $p_j^{e_j}$.